# Break doesn't exit the switch body but moves to its last row

Tags: java, switch-statement, break

I use switch statement in Java and once the program reaches the break statement, instead of exiting the switch it moves to the last row of the switch body and executes it as well.

I have tried it in Debug mode writing in the console "Sofia" and 250. It enters the first switch, finds the "Sofia" case, assigns value to the commission variable, executes the break and than goes to the last row of the switch body and executes the return as well. If I delete the default case altogether, after executing the break it again goes to the last row of the body and executes the break from the third case. Regardless of what I try, executing the break does not seem to exit the body of the switch body and always goes to it's last row.

Do you have any idea why that might be? Here is the code:

```
package SlojniLogicheskiProverki;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Zadacha {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String city = scan.nextLine();
        double sales = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
        double commission = 0;
        if (sales >= 0 && sales <= 500) {
            switch (city) {
                case "Sofia":
                    commission = 5;
                    break;
                case "Plovdiv":
                    commission = 5.5;
                    break;
                case "Varna":
                    commission = 4.5;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("error");
                    return;
            }
        } else if (sales > 500 && sales <= 1000) {
            switch (city) {
                case "Sofia":
                    commission = 7;
                    break;
                case "Plovdiv":
                    commission = 8;
                    break;
                case "Varna":
                    commission = 7.5;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("error");
                    return;
            }
        } else if (sales > 1000 && sales <= 10000) {
            switch (city) {
                case "Sofia":
                    commission = 8;
                    break;
                case "Plovdiv":
                    commission = 12;
                    break;
                case "Varna":
                    commission = 10;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("error");
                    return;
            }
        }
        else if (sales > 10000) {
            switch (city) {
                case "Sofia":
                    commission = 12;
                    break;
                case "Plovdiv":
                    commission = 14.5;
                    break;
                case "Varna":
                    commission = 13;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("error");
                    return;
            }
        }        else {
            System.out.println("error");
            return;
        }
        System.out.printf("d%",commission);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve], ideally using hard-coded data instead of requiring user input.

Comment: I just tried it: and it works as expected (after adjusted format in last line)

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't that `d%` is not a valid format syntax for a double and the problem has nothing to do with any switch and break?

Comment: As Stefan, I have tested (and debugged) your code and got no unexpected behaviour. I can not reproduce your stated problem. I got an exception in the last line that can be solved   `System.out.printf("%f %%", commission);` Use %f to print a double, use %% to print a % symbol.

Comment: Looks to me like you did not save and recompile the project between changing and debugging the source code.

Comment: Changing the incorrect syntax in the printf statement solved the problem, thanks everyone.